# Use insertItem after bindAggregation in Sap.m.Select

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Is my first time posting here.

I have a sap.m.Select that shows the Years from oDataModel using "bindAggregation" method.

My idea is to create a extra Item in the Select with text: "All Values" and Key: "*", So I tried to use the "insertItem" after the "bindAggregation", but the item that I created didnt appear in the Select list of items, only the Years from oDataModel.

Here is the code:

```
var yearSelectBox = this.getView().byId("idYearSelectBox");
yearSelectBox.setModel(new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("../../../ui/WebContent/Kpi/services/dates.xsodata", true));
yearSelectBox.bindAggregation("items", "/Years", new sap.ui.core.Item({
            key: "{YEAR}",
            text: "{YEAR}"
        }),0);
yearSelectBox.insertItem(new sap.ui.core.Item({
            key: "*",
            text: "All Values"
        }));
```

I tried to use the insertItem before the bindAggregation, to use itemIndex = -1, 0, 20, but nothing changed.

Comment: I am curious why its not working..
Insert after bind aggregation..NOT BEFORE
I just created sample JS  fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gjewbaep/

Comment: i tried like you did, but it didnt work, so I created a jsonModel with oDataModel data adding the All Values entry like @hagen said. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to add add 'All' value to <Select> Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085969/whats-the-best-way-to-add-add-all-value-to-select-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're trying to achieve - while making sense to you - doesn't make sense in the context of binding. When you bind a data model to a control, the control then bases all of its rendering on that model. Additionally, any changes via. the control are pushed back to the model - this keeps the model and control in sync. Thus you cannot simply add another item to the aggregation once a binding is in place. The binding controls what items are added (updated and removed), not programmatic interference. You have two simply options (perhaps others too): read your model data into a JSON model, including your *All Values* dropdown entry, then bind the dropdown control to that JSON Model, or add the *All Values* entry to the underlying OData database table so it shows up in the dropdown.