# What's the best way to add add 'All' value to <Select> Control?

Tags: sapui5

//Update: I use this `<select>` control in [Filter Bar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.filterbar.example2/preview)

In  control of UI5，if I select one item, I can't go back to non-selected state, so I want to add 'All' value in items:

This works:

```
<Select>
    <core:Item key="" text="All" />
    <core:Item key="another value" text="another value"/>
</Select>
```

But "All" disapear in this example:

```
<Select
    items="{
        path: '/PRODUCTS'
    }">
    <core:Item key="" text="All" />
    <core:Item key="{ID}" text="{Route_Name}" />
</Select>
```

What should I do?

Comment: A Facet Filter would be better suited to your requirement as it provides a Selection with All as a selection option

Comment: I don't understand fully what you really want to achieve. Why would you want to add an "All"-item if you want the user to select none?

Comment: @boghyon, it's a <select> control in Filter Bar https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfilterbar/preview

Comment: @StephenS , https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.FacetFilterSimple/preview It seems that I need to add `"Filters"` in my data.json to config Facet Filter?

Comment: My question might duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812075/use-insertitem-after-bindaggregation-in-sap-m-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FacetFilter control would suit your requirement. It has an all selection to select all the values in the List.

```
<FacetFilter
            id="idFacetFilter"
            type="Simple"
            confirm="handleConfirm">
            <lists>
                <FacetFilterList
                    title="Route"
                    key="route"
                    mode="MultiSelect"
                    items="{
                        path: '/PRODUCTS'
                    }" >
                    <items>
                        <FacetFilterItem
                            text="{Route_Name}"
                            key="{ID}" />
                    </items>
                </FacetFilterList>
            </lists>
        </FacetFilter>
```

Comment: It works, add `All` without modify the background data. A little bit inconsistent with my datapicker&timepicker design in filter, but I can work with it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to let users to select none item again, I'd recommend using <del>`sap.m.ActionSelect` or</del>* `sap.m.ComboBox` over a basic Select control.

<del>In case of ActionSelect: Turn off forcing selection with `forceSelection:false` and add an action button with a press event handler executing `myActionSelect.close().setSelectedKey("");`.</del>

---

* `sap.m.ActionSelect` is deprecated. Refer to: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/dabdf6427427f36db1135c3c06d52cc4c7f0d7fd

Comment: Tried ActionSelect, but the action button is in the bottom,  hard to find it if there is many data.

Comment: I see. If it's about filtering, you might want to try out [IconTabBar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBar/preview) instead of FilterBar. The user can see clearly his selected filter and you've got the option to remove the filter ("all") as well. Otherwise, if you want to stick with FilterBar, then ComboBox or FacetFilter are great choices as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must add some key value to the item with text="All". Please have a look in the jsbin working [example](http://jsbin.com/kusolucequ/1/edit?html,js,output).

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(
  {
    items:
    [
      { KEY: null, LABEL: "-ALL-"},
      { KEY: "A", LABEL: "A"},
      { KEY: "B", LABEL: "B"},
      { KEY: "C", LABEL: "C"},
      { KEY: "D", LABEL: "D"}
    ]
});

var oSelect = new sap.m.Select({
    items: {
      path: "/items",
      template: new sap.ui.core.Item({ key: "{KEY}", text:"{LABEL}" })
    }
})

oSelect.setModel(oModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

add below where you set Model.

```
var oView = this.getView();
    fnSuccess(oData,oResponse){
        var value = {
                      ID          : "All",
                      Route_Name  : "All",
            };

        oData.results.splice(0,0,value);              // oData your array of data
        var oSelectData = {
                            PRODUCTS : oData
            };

        var oSelectJSON = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oSelectJSON.setData(oSelectData);
        oView.byId("id_select").setModel(oSelectJSON);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quiet understand, `fnSuccess` is a callback function for setModel() or sth.?

Comment: fnSuccess is success function of oData model if you are taking data from back end. otherwise oData mention is fnSuccess function is your own existing array.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating two arrays, one with the 'All' key/value pair, then another with my list of items, then concat() them together. In your JSON view model, declare the array:

`selections[];`

In the onBeforeRendering() lifecycle method, check if the array is populated (< 0), and if so, read the entity set which contains your list:

```
    onBeforeRendering: function() {
        // Build the provinces list
        if (this.getModel("view").getProperty("/selections").length === 0) {
            this.getModel().read("/SelectionList", {
                success: this._setSelections.bind(this)
            });
        }
```

Upon success, build the array and set the property:

```
    _setSelections: function(oResponse) {
        var aSelections = [{
            key: "",
            text: "(All)"
        }];
        if (typeof oResponse.results !== "undefined") {
            aSelections = aSelections.concat(oResponse.results);
        }
        this.getModel("view").setProperty("/selections", aSelections);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @vivek' answer, append an All when data loaded:

```
    onHazardTabBarSelect : function(oEvent) {
        var oTabBar = oEvent.getSource(),
        sSelectedTabId = oTabBar.getSelectedKey(),
        oSelectedTab = sap.ui.getCore().byId(sSelectedTabId),
        sAssignmentPath = oSelectedTab.getBindingContext().getPath();

        this._oModel.read( sAssignmentPath + "/assignedControls", {
            urlParameters: {
                "$expand": "control"
            },
            success: this.addControlSelectData.bind(this), 
            error: this.errorCallback.bind(this)
        });
    },

    addControlSelectData : function(oEvent) {
        var oSelectControl = this.byId("controlSelect"),
        aControlResults = oEvent.results,
        aResult = [{
            "control" : {
                id: "All",
                name: "All"
            }
        }],
        aData = aResult.concat(aControlResults);
        oSelectControl.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(aData));
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combobox and adding a selectAll to the item list should work. Then on the selection change event one can check if the selectAll option has been selected or not(by using  oEvent.getParameter("changedItem")) and then just oEvent.oSource.setSelectedKeys(res) where res is either all the items or just null in case the selectAll option has been deselected.